# Remove Nested <Script> tag from any string using REGEX in vb.net

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net, xss, sanitization

I have a function which sanitize input text string and removes `<script>` tag from it.

```
    Public Shared Function RemoveXssScript(html As String) As String
        Dim data As String = If(html, "")

        Dim pattern As String = "<script\\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\\\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\\\/script>/g"

        While Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            data = Regex.Replace(data, pattern , "")
        End While

        Return data
    End Function
```

Here the Regex doesn't work for nested script tag string.
Below is my test strings:

1.

```
    <'<script></script>script type="text/javascript">al<script>   </script>ert("test");<'<script></script>/script>
```

2.

```
<<script></script>script type="text/javascript">alert("test");<<script></script>/script>
```

3.

```
<'<script></script>script type="text/javascript">al<script></script>ert("test");<'<script></script>/script>
```

I have to strip out all script tag from string using REGEX.If there is no solution for stripping out nested script, probably i have to go with the solution of detecting any one script tag from text and removing out the complete string.

I need a REGEX that detects nested as well as normal script tags and strips it out.
Thanks you.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: I have same function in javascript as well for that i need REGEX.

Comment: How does your filter cope with XSS in the form `<img src="https://invalid" onerror="alert('xss')" />`?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you mean script elements, not script tags, right? Also, in the real world there's no such thing as nested script elements. Scripts can't contain other elements. Anyway, perhaps using a parser is better than a regex.